How can we prove that $\langle p_x\rangle=\hbar k_x$ where $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck's Constant for an essentially free electron?
In my solid state electronics course, I came across this question from the Ben G Streetman and Bannerjee book on 'Solid State Electronic devices'.
​

Assuming the potential energy $U$  is constant for an essentially free electron in a crystal, show that the x -component of the electron's momentum is given by  $p_x = \hbar k_x$ , where $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck's constant and $k_x$ is the wavevector component in the $x$-direction.

I did the research and found that momentum must be replaced with $p_x =−i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}(\Psi(x))$ where $\Psi(x)$ is the probability function. What are the other necessary assumptions I must make in order to solve the question? Please elaborate on the normalisation procedure done here as well.

What we want to know is the expectation value of the momentum in x direction, which is defined as
$$\langle \hat{p}_x\rangle=\int d^3\mathbf{r}\Psi^*\hat{p}_x\Psi\,\, .$$
Here $\Psi$ is the wavefunction of the electron, which we can obtain by solving the Schrödinger equation for a constant potential
$$ E\Psi=\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta+U \right]\Psi\,\, .$$
This can be solved by defining the momentum $k_{x,y,z}=\sqrt{2(E-U)m}/\hbar$. The solution then reads as
$$\Psi=C e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\,\, .$$
The constant C is a normalization constant. You can obtain it by assuming that $1=\int_V d^3\mathbf{r}|\Psi|^2$. Now insert your wavefunction in the first equation and use $\hat{p}_x=-i\hbar\partial/\partial x$ for the momentum operator. Then you get
$$\langle p_x \rangle =\hbar k_x\,\, .$$
Note that the normalization constant vanishes in your calculation.

That should be a nabla, not a delta

No, the delta is the Laplace operator (second partial derivative). The nabla is used for the first partial derivative.

@bergit, when I write it I write nabla^2.  When I did QM, 27 years ago, I didn't use the Laplace operator.  But you're right.  I'm just used to seeing del for partial derivatives
